# Web browser screen capture bitmap too heavy

Tags: c#, image, webbrowser-control

I'm using this code to capture browser screen:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(240, 320);
wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 240, 320));
```

Bitmap file size is 300 kb. I'm storing these images in azure blob storage on multiple threads and it takes too much time to upload. How could I reduce image size without affecting quality too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a format other than BMP, for example PNG or JPEG with a high-quality setting.  Alternatively, ZIP-compress the bitmap before upload.